# Finding inheritors of a class across branches of code

Tags: c#, git, svn, tfs, static-code-analysis

Has anyone attempted something similar to "find inheritors" or "find references" across branches? I'm working with a code base that includes multiple release branches, some of which differ from the main line.

Fortunately, the base code is no different, but there may be classes that inherit that base code. When making redesign decisions, it would be helpful to know which branches might be affected by a redesign. Has anyone run into this in the past and/or knows a good direction in which to point me to find more information on the topic?

I'm working with C#, Visual Studio, and an SVN repository, but if someone has run into this in other code repositories, other languages, or other technologies, the same concepts should apply.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is similar to find difference between branches in TFS. With TFS, we can find difference in VS directly, by right click on the file or folder in Source Control Explorer and choose **Compare**. Or we can use command line tool `tf.exe` to get the difference:

```
tf diff[erence] itemspec [/version:versionspec] [/type:filetype] 
[/format:format [/ignorespace] [/ignoreeol] [/ignorecase] [/recursive] 
[/options][/noprompt][/login:username,[password]]
```

You may check whether SVN has similar command line tool.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Given that the standard is to only inherit from existing code rather than change it, it's non-trivial to find out if an existing class is being inherited or a method overridden (at least not without writing a custom utility to do so). The inheritor could be named anything, and a new source file won't guarantee that something is being inherited. Thanks for the reply though; using a command-line diff could be a good starting point if I write a utility to do something similar.